# R function only the last value of a vector is printed

Tags: r, loops, vector

Thank you for your help with this function, which should :

1. Enter a a specific value
2. Insert the value in a function
3. Take a set of other values generated in a vector
4. Calculate a value for each element of a vector
5. Return a data frame with both vector and calculated values.

Here is what I tried:

```
rate<-function(Y2) {
   ran<-seq(0.001,1,0.001)
   for(i in ran) {
     calculated<-as.vector(Y2/(1+i)+Y2/(1+i)^2+Y2/(1+i)^3+Y2/(1+i)^4)
     tableau<-data.frame(ran,calculated)
   }
   return(tableau)
}
```

When testing with `res<-rate(500)`, only the last value is returned 1000 times:

```
...

ran calculated
1   0.001   468.75
2   0.002   468.75
3   0.003   468.75
...

996  0.996     468.75
997  0.997     468.75
998  0.998     468.75
999  0.999     468.75
1000 1.000     468.75
```

What is wrong with my loop?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the output of your `as.vector(...)` calculation to the same variable each time you loop.  Then you're building a data.frame, named `tableau` each time you loop. You're only returning the last iteration.  If you want to save each iteration, you'll need to index into something:

```
res[n] <- as.vector(...)
```

Or the more R-ish version, use one of the apply family (specifically `lapply`) and no loop at all:

```
rate <- function(Y2) {
    ran <- seq(0.001, 1, 0.001)
    result <- lapply(ran, 
                     function(i) data.frame(ran = i, 
                                            calculated = as.vector(Y2/(1+i)+Y2/(1+i)^2+Y2/(1+i)^3+Y2/(1+i)^4)))

    return (do.call(rbind, result))
}
```

With that said, there is no reason for a loop or an apply function. Use the fact that `R` is vectorized:

```
ran <- seq(0.001, 1, 0.001)
Y2 <- 500

calculated <- as.vector(Y2/(1+ran)+Y2/(1+ran)^2+Y2/(1+ran)^3+Y2/(1+ran)^4)

result <- data.frame(ran, calculated)
```

---

```
all.equal(result, rate(500))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I will certainly use the vectorized solution. Beside this, I have also tested another version with stocking values in previously created vector. I have received a mismatch and I am also wondering why ???
rate<-function(Y2)

  
{
  
  ran<-seq(0.001,1,0.001)

  res<-c()

  for (i in ran)
    
  {
  
  
  res<-c(res,Y2/(1+i)+Y2/(1+i)^2+Y2/(1+i)^3+Y2/(1+i)^4)
  
  tableau<-data.frame(cbind(ran,res))
  
  }
  
  return(tableau)
  
}

Comment: Here the calculation operates, but vector rows are badly bound with a mismatch in the resulting dataframe. Thanks for your ideas, Justin.

Comment: Please either add that to your question, or better yet, ask a new one... However, I think the moral of the story is to stop using for loops like that.  "growing" a vector like you're doing with `res` is one of the slowest and most memory inefficient things you can do in R.