# Looping Sum for Word-filled function

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, sum

I've set up a **list**:

```
Dow30 <- c("MMM","AXP","T","BA","CAT","CVX","CSCO","DD","XOM","GE","GS","HD","INTC","IBM","JNJ","JPM", "MCD","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG","KO","TRV","UTX","UNH","VZ","V","WMT","DIS")
```

I want each of the items (individually, in quotes) **looped** through my function, SumProfitOnly, and then the (numeric) returns for each item **summed all together**.

This **longhand method** gets me the final answer I'm looking for ...

```
print(SumProfitOnly("DIS") + SumProfitOnly("MMM") + SumProfitOnly("AXP") + SumProfitOnly("T") + SumProfitOnly("BA") + SumProfitOnly("CAT") + SumProfitOnly("CVX") + SumProfitOnly("CSCO") + SumProfitOnly("DD") + SumProfitOnly("XOM") + SumProfitOnly("GE") + SumProfitOnly("GS") + SumProfitOnly("HD") + SumProfitOnly("INTC") + SumProfitOnly("IBM") + SumProfitOnly("JNJ") + SumProfitOnly("JPM") + SumProfitOnly("MCD") + SumProfitOnly("MRK") + SumProfitOnly("MSFT") + SumProfitOnly("NKE") + SumProfitOnly("PFE") + SumProfitOnly("PG") + SumProfitOnly("KO") + SumProfitOnly("TRV") + SumProfitOnly("UTX") + SumProfitOnly("UNH") + SumProfitOnly("VZ") + SumProfitOnly("V") + SumProfitOnly("WMT"))
```

... but I'm trying to make a **quicker function** work.

My **(failed)** efforts:

1) Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221903/r-function-only-the-last-value-of-a-vector-is-printed) related issue --

```
rate <- function(n) {
    result <- lapply(n, function(i) data.frame(n = i, calculated = as.vector(SumProfitOnly(i))))

    return(do.call(rbind, result))
}

print(rate(Dow30))
```

This yields each individual result in a **dataframe** (along with the original text ticker, no quotes).  Looks like this:

```
      n calculated
1   MMM       4.01
2   AXP       3.31
3     T      -1.05
4    BA      -0.77
5   CAT       3.40
6   CVX       1.90
7  CSCO       2.46
8    DD       3.95
9   XOM       2.03
etc., etc., etc.
```

I've tried to shove a **sum** around things, but it either ignores the **sum function**, or comes up with an **error**, like after this attempt of altering the print:

```
print(sum(rate(Dow30)), na.rm = FALSE)
```

Giving the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

2) Based on another answered issue:

```
for (n in Dow30)
{
printer[n] = print(SumProfitOnly(n))    
}
```

Yielding this:

```
[1] 4.01
[1] 3.31
[1] -1.05
[1] -0.77
[1] 3.4
[1] 1.9
[1] 2.46
[1] 3.95
[1] 2.03
etc., etc., etc.,
```

Here, once again, adding sum inside and out of the function is not successful, as it only returns the "sum" of the **last value** in my list.

Comment: Give `sapply(Dow30, SumProfitOnly)` a try?  It's hard to tell without the SumProfitOnly function.  And an fyi, you don't need to wrap things with `print()`.  They will print in the console without it.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)